# position in CSS

Tags: css

what is difference between relative position and absolute position is CSS
eg
.style
{
position:relative;
}

.style
{
position:absolute;
}

Comment: Everything you need to know in a hands-on quick tutorial, very good. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard describes it here: [Comparison of normal flow, floats, and absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comparison)

Is there something in particular about this which you don't understand or want explaining further?

Answer (score 5):

From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp):

> **Absolute**
>
> Generates an absolutely positioned
>   element, positioned relative to the
>   first parent element that has a
>   position other than static. The
>   element's position is specified with
>   the "left", "top", "right", and
>   "bottom" properties
>
> **Relative**
>
> Generates a relatively positioned
>   element, positioned relative to its
>   normal position, so "left:20" adds 20
>   pixels to the element's LEFT position

Also check [this page](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/), it will give you very nice overview about positions in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

With relative you can position the element relative to its original position and the original space is still holding the item.

Absolute takes the item out of the regular flow of the HTML and you can position it relative to the parent element.

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: not necessarily - if the parent-element has position:relative/absolute/fixed, absolute positioning will be relative to the parent-element.

Comment: Relative to the first parent element that is positioned in any way, if there is none, it will be relative to the body element

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial about that:

http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Position_absolute_is_really_relative%3F

Answer (score 1):

Use **relative** when you consider range to parent element or elements before.

Use **absolute** when you want to make an element in inviolable position.

You can also learn the difference between margin-left and left css property for relative and absolute

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:300px; height:200px; margin:auto; background:red">
        <div style="position:relative; left:10px; top:20px;">
            test
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative; left:10px; top:20px;">
            test
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0px;">
            test
        </div>
                    <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:0; margin-bottom:0px;">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```